# How to select multiple cells in column

Tags: windows, vba, excel

So far I am able to enter a word in an input box and have it return how many times that certain word occurs within a certain column. What I want it to do is select each cell that the inputted word occurs in. Or alternatively, highlight each cell the word occurs in. Here is what I have already:

```
Sub wordcounter()
Dim word As String
Dim count As Integer
word = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter word to search: ", Title:="Enter Word", Default:="Search        word")
For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("G").Cells
    cell.Value = LCase(cell.Value)
    If InStr(cell.Value, word) Then
        cell.select
    End If
    If InStr(cell.Value, word) Then
        count = count + 1
    End If
Next cell
    MsgBox (word & " = " & count)
End Sub
```

This code only selects the last cell in which the word occurs. Any ideas on how to select all of the cells with the word instead of just the last cell?

Comment: You could also use conditional formatting to achieve the highlighting part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do it, avoiding the loop altogether to speed up and simplify:

```
Sub sWordcounter()
Dim sWord As String
Dim count As Integer
sWord = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter Word to search: ", Title:="Enter Word", Default:="Search Word")

With ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("G").Cells
    .AutoFilter
    .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="*" & sWord & "*"
    .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    .AutoFilter
End With

End Sub
```

You can adjust the .Select portion to anything you want to do to the cell.

Comment: + 1 Damn! After I posted my answer, I saw your comment about conditional formatting under OP's post :) Had to delete my answer :( Next time will be carefull to read the comments :P

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `cell.select` you could highlight it by making it a different color using:

```
cell.InteriorColor.Color = RGB(#, #, #)
```

I am not sure what you are using this for, hope this helps.